# Can foreach reading the same csv generate an error?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I want to understand when doing a foreach loop that involves reading a csv from a given folder, will there be clashes leading to stopping of the foreach loop if by chance the file is being accessed by multiple cores at the same time. Below is a simplication of my problem:

For e.g. I have three folders each representing a location and a csv file under these folders have a parameter value as follows:

```
setwd('C:/test')

my.vec <- letters[1:3]
for(i in my.vec){
  
  dir.create(file.path(getwd(), i))
  
  temp.dat <- data.frame(location = i, param = runif(1))
  
  write.csv(temp.dat, file.path(getwd(), i , paste0('dat_param.csv')))
}
```

I have another data.frame with two columns: one with location and the other with some value `x`

```
  my.dat <- data.frame(location = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = T),
                        value = runif(100))
```

For each row in `my.dat`, I want to read the corresponding location's param value and multiply to the value as follows:

```
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  
  myClusters <- makeCluster(6) 
  registerDoParallel(myClusters)
  
  results <- 
    
    foreach(i = 1:nrow(my.dat), .combine = 'rbind') %dopar% 
    {
      
      temp <- my.dat[i, ]
      
      temp.dat <- read.csv(file.path(getwd(), temp$location , paste0('dat_param.csv'))))
      
      temp$rev.value <- temp$value * temp.dat$param
      
      return(temp)
    }
            
  stopCluster(myClusters)
```

My question is in the foreach loop where I am reading the csv file, could there by instances
when multiple cores are trying to read the same csv and that might cause some error?
If yes, how do I resolve it?

Comment: You should be fine reading from the same file as long as no one is trying to change the file on disk. Are you experiencing some error that makes you think this is a problem?

Comment: I am not experiencing an error. As part of designing my code, I had to brainstorm whether this could be a potential issue. Thank you for your response